# I Am Making A Text Based Rpg For My Programing Class And Have Encountered Errors

Tags: java, loops

in my code i use x and y cords to move around in game and it should be working properly but on line about 490 it is giving me an else without if even though there is one and when i try to use wasd it goes somewhere it should'ent
(sorry for code dump i could'ent pinpoint the problem i am new to java)

```
  /**
     * @(#)FSE.java
     *
     * FSE application
     *
     * @author 
     * @version 1.00 2015/1/7
     */
         import java.io.*;
         import java.util.Random;
        public class FSE {

        public static void main(String[] args) {    

          BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          // Declaring Variables
            String Name, Move, Attack;
            int x, y, Combat, Creature, HP, HP2, Strike, Strike2, loop;
            x=0;
            y=0; 
            Combat=0;
            Creature=0;
            Move="";
            Attack="";
            HP=0;
            HP2=0;
            Strike=0;
            Strike2=0;
            loop=0;
                    // Introduction to start the game off
            System.out.println("Your Awake Traveler Do You Remember What   Happened");
            try {
          Thread.sleep(2500L);
            }
    catch (Exception e) {}  
                System.out.println("You Look Around At What looks Like A Old Cave And See A Colapsed Entrance To The North");
                    try {
          Thread.sleep(2500L);
            }
    catch (Exception e) {}
            System.out.println("Do Remember What Your Name Is");
                try{
                    Name=input.readLine();
                 }

                 catch (IOException ioe){
                    System.out.println("input error");
                 }
                 while(loop==0){
                    System.out.println("What Way Would You Like To Navigate Use WASD To Choose A Direction");
                 try{
                    Move=input.readLine();
                 }
                 // Movement Control Keys
                 catch (IOException ioe){
                    System.out.println("input error");          
                 }  
                 if(Move.equals("w")){ // Upward Movement
                    y+=1;   
                    System.out.println("*****"+y);
                 }  
                 else if(Move.equals("d")){ // Right Movement
                    x+=1;
                 }  
                 else if(Move.equals("s")){ // Downward Movement
                    y-=1;
                 }  
                 else{
                    x-=1; // Left Movement Key ("a")
                 }
                 if (y==-1 && x==0){ // First-Entrance into the game's combat
                    System.out.println("You have now entered the cave.");
                    Combat=1;
                    while(Combat==1);{
                        System.out.println("A Goblin Has Attacked");
                        HP=20;
                        HP2=8;
                        System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
                        try{
                            Attack=input.readLine();
                        }
                        catch (IOException ioe){
                            System.out.println("input error");          
                        }   
                        if(Attack.equals("A")){
                            Random randomGenerator=new Random();
                            Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
                            Strike+=5;
                            HP2-=Strike;
                            System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
                            System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
                            Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
                            Strike2+=5;
                            HP-=Strike2;
                            System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
                            System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
                            if(HP<=0){
                                System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            else if(HP2<=0){
                                Combat=0;
                                System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
                            }

                            }
                            }               
                             }
                else if (y==-2 && x==0){ // Path leading downwards from entrance pointt
    System.out.println("You have entered a new room in the cave!");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Imp Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=7;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Imp Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
    Strike2+=2;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Imp Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Imp And May Continue In Your Quest"); 
    }

    }
    } 
                }   
    else if (y==-3 && x==0){
       System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
       Combat=1;
           while(Combat==1);{
              System.out.println("A Goblin Has Attacked"); 
              HP=20;
              HP2=8;
              System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
              try{
                 Attack=input.readLine();
              }
              catch (IOException ioe){
                 System.out.println("input error");          
              } 
              if(Attack.equals("A")){
                 Random randomGenerator=new Random();
                 Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
                 Strike+=5;
                 HP2-=Strike; 
                 System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
                 System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
                 Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
                 Strike2+=5;
                 HP-=Strike2;
        System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
        System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
        if(HP<=0){
                System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
        System.exit(0);
        }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-4 && x==0){
    System.out.println("You have entered the final room on the path! The path does not go any further.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Troll Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=10;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Troll Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(7);
    Strike2+=7;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Troll Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Troll And May Continue In Your Quest");   
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-1 && x==1){ // Right path from the entrance point
    System.out.println("You have entered a new room in the cave!");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Goblin Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-1 && x==2){
    System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Giant Spider Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Giant Spider Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(6);
    Strike2+=6;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Giant Spider Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Giant Spider And May Continue In Your Quest");    
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-1 && x==3){
    System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Imp Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Imp Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
    Strike2+=2;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Imp Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
        System.out.println("You Died. Game Over."); 
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Imp And May Continue In Your Quest"); 
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-2 && x==3){ //Path going downwards towards the boss
    System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Giant Spider Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-3 && x==3){
    System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Goblin Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-4 && x==3){
    System.out.println("You have entered the next room.");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("A Goblin Has Attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=8;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Goblin And May Continue In Your Quest");  
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    else if (y==-4 && x==1){
    System.out.println("You have entered the final room in the cave! You are now in the Demon's Domain!"); //Final Boss Battle
    System.out.println("*"+y+"*"+x+"*");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("The Demon has attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=15;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(8);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Demon! Conagradulations!");   
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    }
        else if (y==-4 && x==2){
    System.out.println("You have entered the final room in the cave! You are now in the Demon's Domain!"); //Final Boss Battle
    system.out.println("*"+y+"*"+x+"*");
    Combat=1;
    while(Combat==1);{
    System.out.println("The Demon has attacked");
    HP=20;
    HP2=15;
    System.out.println("Press A To Attack");
    try{
    Attack=input.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
    System.out.println("input error");          
    }   
    if(Attack.equals("A")){
    Random randomGenerator=new Random();
         Strike=randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    Strike+=5;
    HP2-=Strike;
    System.out.println("You Did "+Strike+" Damage");
    System.out.println("The Goblin Has "+HP2+" Life Left");
         Strike2=randomGenerator.nextInt(8);
    Strike2+=5;
    HP-=Strike2;
    System.out.println("The Goblin Did "+Strike2+" Damage");
    System.out.println("You Have "+HP+" Life Left");
    if(HP<=0){
            System.out.println("You Died. Game Over.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(HP2<=0){
    Combat=0;
    System.out.println("You Have Defeated The Demon! Conagradulations!");   
    }

    }
    }    
    }
    }
    // Spaces in the game where you are not allowed to go
    if (y==1 && x==0);{
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=0;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==0 && x==-1){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=0;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==0 && x==1){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==0 && x==2){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=2;
    }
    else if (y==0 && x==3){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=3;
    }
    else if (y==-1 && x==4){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=3;
    }
    else if (y==-2 && x==4){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-2;
    x=3;
    }
    else if (y==-3 && x==4){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-3;
    x=3;
    }
    else if (y==-4 && x==4){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-4;
    x=3;
    }
    else if (y==-5 && x==0){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-4;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==-2 && x==1){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==-2 && x==-2){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-1;
    x=3;
    }   
    else if (y==-3 && x==1){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-3;
    x=0;
    }
    else if (y==-5 && x==3){
    System.out.println("You cannot go this way.");
    y=-4;
    x=3;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You cannot go this way")
            y=-3;
            x=3;
    }       

            }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that is a massive code dump. If you expect anyone to help, you should do some debugging yourself and narrow down where this issue is occurring, and then post only the relevant code. And please make an effort to indent your code, it makes it much more readable.

Comment: It may be worth checking that the condition of the loop is not being met after the first iteration. However, it is *really* hard to tell with this code dump.

Comment: You should consider using object-oriented design in your program.

Comment: Stop lying. Your code should not even compile with this line of code : ` system.out.println("*"+y+"*"+x+"*");` . It should be `System`. I bet there are other issues as well.

Comment: im sorry i am new to java and im just learning as well as first time using this website sorry for the code dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me 3 tries to copy and paste your code from Stack Overflow.

You had 4 syntax errors.  The code you pasted wouldn't even compile.

Your biggest problem is that your entire Java application is one method (main).

Java is designed so that you can break up your code into many, many, many, many methods, and if necessary, many classes.  When you create something this involved, you should use a [model / view / controller (MVC) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The MVC pattern allows you to separate your concerns and for you to be able to focus on one small part of your program at a time.

Let's look at your introduction first.  You twice display a message, and then wait.  Here's how you can create a method to do this.

```
private static void displayMessageAndWait(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

With this method, your introduction now looks like this.

```
    // Introduction to start the game off
    String message = "You're Awake Traveler. Do You Remember What Happened?";
    displayMessageAndWait(message);
    message = "You Look Around At What looks Like A Old Cave " +
            "And See A Collapsed Entrance To The North.";
    displayMessageAndWait(message);
```

Do you see how creating a method documents what the code is doing?  By breaking up your code into tiny, tiny pieces, and putting those pieces in a method, you make your Java application easier for you to understand, and for others to understand.

Next, we'll look at the get name piece.  We'll put the code in a method called getName.  Clever, eh.

```
private static String getName(BufferedReader input) {
    System.out.println("Do You Remember What Your Name Is?");
    try {
        String name = input.readLine();
        return name;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now, the code in the main method looks like this.

```
    name = getName(input);
```

Java variable names and method names start with a lower case letter.  This is so we can distinguish between a class name and a method name or variable name at a glance.

All I've done so far is break up your code.  The real power of Java is when you create classes that can be used to model your Java application.

Here's a Room model class, as an example.

```
public class Room {

    private boolean isCreatureInRoom;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private String description;

    public Room(int x, int y, String description) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.description = description;
        this.isCreatureInRoom = false;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public boolean isCreatureInRoom() {
        return isCreatureInRoom;
    }

    public void setCreatureInRoom(boolean isCreatureInRoom) {
        this.isCreatureInRoom = isCreatureInRoom;
    }

}
```

Now, we can create as many rooms as we like by making an instance of the Room class for each room that we want.

Hopefully, this is enough information for you to go back and break your program apart into many methods and classes.

Comment: ok im sorry i've never used boolean's or other code you used or multipile class's so im not sure how i would go about implementing the code you posted here im sorry im new to java im just looking for some help